# My HTC desire C says 'type password to decrypt storage' and I can't remember my password

Tags: storage, htc, password, encryption, htc-desire-c

I got a new phone and am trying to sell my old HTC desire C with beats audio. When I turn it on it says 'type password to decrypt storage' but I can't remember my password, any way I can overcome this? It has no SIM card either.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> Power off your device and wait for 5-10 seconds until the device is
>   fully switched off. Press and hold Volume Down button, then press the
>   Power button to switch on your phone and release it, but keep holding
>   the Volume Down button. └ This will boot your HTC Desire C into
>   bootloader mode You’ll see a screen with option to boot into Recovery
>   mode among several other options. Here, press Volume down once to
>   navigate to RECOVERY, then press Power button to select it and boot
>   into Recovery mode. └ In Bootloader and Recovery mode, use Volume
>   buttons to navigate Up and Down between options and use Power button
>   to select an option.

Credit: http://www.theandroidsoul.com/boot-htc-desire-c-recovery-mode-52061/

You should have an option to wipe device. Unfortunately, if you forget your password, all of your data is just gibberish.

Comment: Note: What Wilhelm describes is basically how to achieve a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) – all your apps and data will be lost, the device will be "pure" as if you'd just received it. But Wilhelm is right: with your encryption password forgotten, your data is lost anyway.